# SQL count by type

Tags: sql

I would like to summarize in a table so that I have for each **id** in each **round**,
the number of tokens “red” and “blue”. What would the SQL query for such table?

Here's the data.

```
id | round | color | ntokens
1  |   1   | blue  | 5
1  |   2   |  red  | 83
1  |   3   | blue  | 77
2  |   3   | blue  | 3
2  |   3   |  red  | 2
3  |   1   |  red  | 4
3  |   1   | blue  | 55
3  |   2   | blue  | 22
```

The result will display like below:

```
id | round | blue_count | red_count
 1 |   1   |      5     |    0
 1 |   2   |      0     |    83
 1 |   3   |     77     |    0
 2 |   3   |      3     |    2
 3 |   1   |     44     |    4
 3 |   2   |     22     |    0
```

I have been trying the following code:

```
  SELECT id, round,
  COUNT(color='red') as red_count,
  COUNT(color='blue') as blue_count
  FROM data
  GROUP BY id, round
```

Comment: For example: `count(case when color ='red' then 1 end)`  Nulls don't count..  but are you "Counting" or "Suming" the ntockets of 77 in base and results seems suspicious as does 5 and 83...

Comment: @xQbert `SUM` not `COUNT`

Comment: Do you need to count occourences or sum the ntokens column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this to get to the requested result table:

```
SELECT 
    id, round,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN ntokens END) AS red_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN ntokens END) AS blue_count
FROM data
GROUP BY id, round
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` counts values that are not `null`. `=` returns either `true` or `false`, which are both not `null`. You could use a `case` expression to create the desired behavior though:

```sql
SELECT   id,
         round,
         COUNT(CASE color WHEN 'red' THEN 1 END) as red_count,
         COUNT(CASE color WHEN 'blue' THEN 1 END) as blue_count
FROM     data
GROUP BY id, round
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about count values. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a CASE in the COUNT.

```
SELECT id, round,
SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN 1 END) as red_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 END) as blue_count
FROM table_that_I_hope_is_not_actually_called_data
GROUP BY id, round
```